# Alternatives to write code with eval in Racket

Tags: racket, eval

```
#lang plait
number: DIGIT number

eval(0) = 0
eval(1) = 1
eval(2) = 2
...
eval(9) = 9

eval(DIGIT) = DIGIT
eval(DIGIT number) = 10*eval(DIGIT) + eval(number)
```

Documentation from Racket states that `eval` can only be used in DrRacket's interaction windows. How can I write this in definition window?

Comment: What language are you using? The syntax doesn't look like the same [`#lang plait`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/plait/index.html) language from the default package server...

Comment: I think it's a pseudocode that can be written in ```lang_plait```.